# SQL Connections: open and close a connection every time you need to execute a query vs keep a connection open?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-connection

I have a small C# app that executes queries every 10 seconds. Should I open and close the connection every time I execute a query (method #2) or keep it open until I close the app (method #1)?

Method #1:

```
class A
{
     A()
     {
           connection.open()
     }

     public void fct()
     {
           //do stuff
     }

     ~A()
     {
           connection.close()
     }
}
```

Method #2:

```
class A
{
     A()
     {
     }

     public void fct()
     {
           connection.open();
           //do stuff
           connection.close();
     }

     ~A()
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: open and close the connection every time

Comment: also, remember that you can use the connection pool to leverage the overall costs of physically opening and closing a connection to the your DBMS. When you open and close a connection with a connection pool, you'll logically close the connection but leaving the physical connection open to be reused until it expires. This is indeed useful in these scenarios.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both answers were useful.